# searching between two csv output in python

Tags: python, csv

Guys I have written this code which ssh to server using paramiko module and get output in csv format for couple of commands. Here is the code and output:-

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('isi nfs exports list --verbose --format=csv') 
nfs_exports = (stdout.read().decode(encoding='ascii'))
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('isi sync policies list --format=csv | grep True')
active_sync = (stdout.read().decode(encoding='ascii'))

print(nfs_exports)

16,System,"/test/true/usa/synctest","true
29,System,"/test/lab/Lab_File_Pool_1",false
32,System,"/test/vipr/Lab_File_Pool_1",false
33,System,"/test/testing2/apps001",null

print(active_sync)

synctest,/test/nam/test/synctest,sync,True,target.domain123.com
synctest,/test/lab/Lab_File_Pool_1,sync,True,target.domain123.com
synctest,/test/nar/usa/synctest,sync,True,target.domain123.com
synctest,/test/testing2/apps001,sync,True,target.domain123.com
synctest,/test/true/usa/synctest,sync,True,target.domain123.com
```

Now the challenging part for me is I need to search for path ("/test/true/usa/synctest") from nfs_exports output in active_sync output. If path matches I need to create new CSV output with  all the information from nfs_export.

Desired Output is:-

```
33,System,"/test/testing2/apps001",null
29,System,"/test/lab/Lab_File_Pool_1",false
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would parse the CSV strings into a more usable format. You could use the `csv` library or `re` (regular expressions).

Then, if I understand the question correctly, it should just be a simple double-nested for loop.

```
for each line in one output:
    for each line in the other output:
        do the paths on the two lines match?
```

```py
import csv
import io

def parse_csv(string):
    string_file = io.StringIO(string)
    reader = csv.reader(string_file)
    return list(reader)


nfs_exports = parse_csv(nfs_exports)
active_sync = parse_csv(active_sync)

print(nfs_exports)
print(active_sync)

results = []

for active_sync_line in active_sync:
    active_sync_path = active_sync_line[1]
    for nfs_export_line in nfs_exports:
        nfs_export_path = nfs_export_line[2]
        if nfs_export_path.strip() == active_sync_path.strip():
            results.append(nfs_export_line)

print("output:")
for line in results:
    print(",".join(line))
```

This gives the output:

```
29,System,/test/lab/Lab_File_Pool_1,false
33,System,/test/testing2/apps001,null
16,System,/test/true/usa/synctest,true
```

Which is a little different than what you posted but if I understand what you were asking correctly it should be right. If not -- please let me know and I can amend this answer.